# Definite Integral: Proving $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x \cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}dx = 2\pi^{2}$

Tags: integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals, proof-explanation

There's a question, to prove that:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x \cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}dx = 2\pi^{2}$$
I want to know where am I going wrong? Here's my approach:

Taking **Left Hand Side**
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{x \cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}dx = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{(2\pi-x)\cos(2\pi-x)}{1+\cos(2\pi-x)}dx$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{(2\pi-x)\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}dx$$
$$=\int_0^\pi\frac{x\cos(x)+(2\pi-x)\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}dx$$
$$=\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos(x)(x+2\pi-x)}{1+\cos(x)}dx$$
$$=2\pi\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}dx$$
$$=2\pi\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos x+1-1}{1+cos x} \, dx = 2\pi\int_0^\pi \bigg(1-\frac{1}{1+\cos x}\bigg)dx$$
$$=2\pi\bigg[x-\tan\frac{x}{2}\bigg]_0^\pi$$
Now if we evaluate this we'll get an undefined result, which is definitely $\neq 2\pi^2$. So, exactly where am I going wrong?

Please pardon me if I'm making the silliest mistake of all time, but please notify where am I wrong.

Comment: Where is the question from? The integrand blows up around $x = \pi$, and in fact is of order $(x-\pi)^{-2}$, which means it's not integrable.

Comment: @JoeyZou This question is in my high school mathematics book. This question was also asked in the ISC Class 12 board exam of 2006. You can take a look at it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Rt57neREbRaWczR2tkUGdZLVk Go to question no. 6 part (a).

Comment: the integral doesn't exist even in a principal value sense :(

Comment: @ShuvamShah Recognizing these kind of questions and having a $\pi^2$ in the proposed answer, I think there should be a $cos^2$ term in the denominator instead of just $cos$.  Possible?

Comment: @imranfat WA tells me, that the integral would be zero in this case

Comment: @tired. Yes, that is actually true, the limits of the integral have to be different. It's just that in these kind of integrals, having a $\pi^2$ in the answer is not uncommon

Answer (score 5):

This integral diverges. $1+\cos x = 1 - \cos(\pi -x) $, hence around $x=\pi$ the denominator behaves like $\frac 12(\pi-x)^2$, which gives us a non-integrable singularity.

Comment: Yes, the integral diverges.